# Variables not being updated by setters

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, setter

Im creating a tetris game, and want the user to be able to choose their board size, from 3 different sizes. I have a Board backend that handles the right, left, down, drop movements, and I have a BoardGUI that creates the shapes and animates it. So when updating the size I need to both update the backend and my GUI for the board. My size keeps getting initialized back to 10 x 20 which is the default size.

here is my BoadGUI snippet (I deleted all unnecessary code, i may have missed something, sorry)

```
public class BoardGUI extends JPanel implements Observer {

private static final int BLOCK_WIDTH = 20;

private Board myBoard;
private MainGUI myFrame;
private int myWidth;
private int myHeight;

public BoardGUI(MainGUI theFrame, int theWidth, int theHeight){
    myWidth = theWidth;
    myHeight = theHeight;
    this.myBoard = new Board(myWidth, myHeight);
    this.myFrame = theFrame;
    setupComponents();
    myBoard.newGame();

}
public Board getBoard() {
    return myBoard;
}
public void setPanelSize(int theWidth, int theHeight){ // gets correct values
    this.myWidth = theWidth;
    this.myHeight = theHeight;
}

private void setupComponents() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(myWidth * BLOCK_WIDTH,  myHeight * BLOCK_WIDTH)); // setting this panel size
    System.out.println(myWidth + " " + myHeight); // DOES NOT PRINT CORRECT SIZE
    myFrame.pack();

}
```

here is my MainGUI where I set the size

```
private int myWidth;
private int myHeight;


public MainGUI() {
    super();
    myWidth = 10;
    myHeight = 20;

}

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5056050661369885282L;
private JMenuBar myMenuBar;
public void start() {
    setTitle("Tetris");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    myEastPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    NextPiece nextPanel = new NextPiece();
    myBoardGUI = new BoardGUI(this, myWidth, myHeight);
    myMainBoard = myBoardGUI.getBoard();
    setResizable(false);

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
 }
 public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
    myMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    myWindow = new JMenu("Window");
    final JFrame frame = this;
    myMenuBar.add(myWindow);
    setWindowSize();
    myMenuBar.setVisible(true);

    return myMenuBar;


}
private void setWindowSize() {
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    JCheckBox def = new JCheckBox("Default");
    JCheckBox size1 = new JCheckBox("150 x 250");
    myWindow.add(def);
    myWindow.addSeparator();
    myWindow.add(size1);
    group.add(def);
    group.add(size1);
    JFrame frame = this;
    def.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            myWidth = 10;
            myHeight = 20;
             myBoardGUI.setPanelSize(myWidth,myHeight); //setting here

        }

    });
    size1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           // myBoardGUI.setPanelSize(15, 25);
            myWidth = 15;
            myHeight = 25;
            myBoardGUI.setPanelSize(myWidth,myHeight); // Setting here


        }

    });
}
```

Comment: It would be quite nice for us (and you since this would likely help you get an answer here quickly) if you could create and post a valid [mcve] (please read the link for the important details of this useful tool), one we could run, test and modify.

Answer (score 3):

You save the variables, but you never reset the preferred size.

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(myWidth * BLOCK_WIDTH,  myHeight * BLOCK_WIDTH));
```

The problem is that you should NOT be using the setPreferredSize() method. This makes the size fixed NOT dynamic.

Instead you **SHOULD** be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of your panel. Something like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(myWidth * BLOCK_WIDTH,  myHeight * BLOCK_WIDTH)); 
}
```

This will allow the size to be dynamically calculated whenever Swing needs to do so.

Now in your `panel.setSize()` method after you update the variables you need to invoke:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

So the layout manager can be invoked and the new size of the panel will be considered.